# DJANGO sending user trought href and HttpResponse error

Tags: python, django, href

So i'm trying to send a parameter trough url /Scan/{id}, in the HTML page:

```
<a href="/scan/{{c.id}}">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> Scan</button>
</a>
```

The url.py:

```
url(r'^scan/(?P<idcmp>\w{0,50})/$', 'projman.views.scanning', name="scan"),
```

The view.py:

```
def scanning(request, idcmp):
    context = init()
```

The error after clicking the a href

The view projman.views.scanning didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

I have the same code in other parts of my site and it works. I have no idea what's happenning.

Comment: Where is the rest of that `scanning` view?

Comment: context = init()

 tmp_component = component.objects.filter(pk=idcmp)[0]

 print tmp_component
 print tmp_component.scanned

 project(request, tmp_component.project.tla)

Just for testing purposes. I dont think the problem is in the function

Comment: Of course it's in the function. The error message is clear: you didn't return an HttpResponse. And, indeed, you don't return anything from the function. Where else would the problem be?

Answer (score 0):

```
def scanning(request, idcmp):
    context = init()
    return HttpResponse('ok')
```

but simply resolve your issue, probably you should add some try..except. and is not clear what idcmp is used for.

one question about `"/scan/{{c.id}}"`: what is `c`? Usually `id` are integer so your url should be

```
url(r'^scan/(?P<idcmp>\d+)/$', 'projman.views.scanning', name="scan"),
```

Comment: What happens if i want to send to another funcion? 

Button pressed -> scanning -> SHowprojects


def scanning(request, idcmp):
 context = init()

 tmp_component = component.objects.filter(pk=idcmp)[0]

 print tmp_component
 print tmp_component.project.tla


 project(request, tmp_component.project.tla)

Comment: another functio ? django views are not built for what you want. they must return a `HttpResponse` object.